# Unable to get the 2nd Parameters of URL in Rewrite rule of .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am having another problem in getting 2nd Get Parameter of my Route i am unable to get the 2nd parameter here is the rule i wrote:

```
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/topics/([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\?page=([0-9]+)?$ topic.php?id=$1&page=$3 [NC,L]
```

the expected URL is

```
knowledgebase/topics/6457-microsoft-office-application-information?page=2
```

here `6457` is the first get variable then `-` then title `microsoft-office-application-information` then `?page=` then my 2nd get parameter that is  `2` but unable to get that page variable

what is the problem is something wrong in Regex ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is not included in the rewrite url pattern. From [RewriteRule Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **What is matched?**
>   If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

You must extract that part separately

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/topics/([0-9]+)-[A-Za-z0-9-]+ topic.php?id=$1&page=%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks mate for answer i will try it and will let you know