# RewriteRule on static url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm putting online a new version of my site and i have to redirect some old indexed pages to the new ones.
So i have generated an htaccess based on static urls (the old ones redirecting to the new ones).

It work for some of them but it figure out that it make 404 errors on the ones that own get parameters (I think that's the cause).

There is 2 rules, the working one and the one that fails :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#Working one
RewriteRule old_page_indexed.htm http://newsite.com [R=301,L] 
#Not working
RewriteRule PBBios.asp?PBMInit=1 http://newsite.com [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

I've tried to following but not working :

```
RewriteRule PBBios.asp\?PBMInit=1 http://newsite.com
RewriteRule ^PBBios.asp\?PBMInit=1$ http://newsite.com
```

Do you have any idea how to do this in htaccess?

Thanks a lot =)

Comment: As it happens, I answered a similar question a few days ago. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14899735/1741542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test against the path and query string independently

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^PBBios.asp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PBMInit=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Okay i tought there was a shortest way. For 100 url (with no logic) it will take many lines. 

So I did it in php ^^'

Thanks for your answers!