# Rewriting URLs with one query string to another URL with a different query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I'm trying to accomplish some redirects as follows:

```
#Basic Rule Set
RewriteRule ^/path$ http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/path/index.html$ http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000 [R=301]
```

which work fine.

However, redirects with query strings in source and destination return me to the above destination url. For e.g.,

```
# Advanced  Rule Set
RewriteRule ^/path/index.html?var=foo$ http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000?id=hello  [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/path/index.html?var=bar$ http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000?id=byebye [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/path/index.html?var=xyz$ http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000?id=world  [R=301]
```

all redirect to `http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000`.
I've tried a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=(.*)$ [NC]` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/index.html [NC]` preceding the above three rules, and still I'm redirected to `http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000`. I've swaped the order of the Basic and Advanced rule sets, and all redirect to `http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000`.

Any ideas on how I might get these rule sets to work? CentOS 6.x, Apache 2.2.

Comment: The query is not present in the rule's URI-path. You have to test it with `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/14899735/1741542

Comment: @faa: I did try it with `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=(.*) [NC]` with the same result. Note, `%1` is not used in the destination URL.

Comment: @faa: Did you delete your answer? I was able to use that to get things working. If you'd like, post it again, and I shall accept it. Thanks for your help! (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this instead:

```
# Advanced  Rule Set
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var=foo [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/index.html/? http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000?id=hello  [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var=bar [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/index.html/? http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000?id=byebye [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var=xyz [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/index.html/? http://newhost.com/Page?pagename=form1000?id=world  [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: If there are loops, please let me know.

Comment: @KM. The rules are for one .htaccess file. If they are in the main configuration files, a leading slash has to be added to `path`, like this `^/path...`, as you have in the question. If there is any problem, please let me know.

Comment: You are welcome @KM. Thanks for letting me know after I deleted it.